# why memory grows crazy if 'N' threads created via TPL with EventWaitHandle

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

while working on TPL I observed a problem. and I want to understand why we have such a behavior.

This is a simple sample code. Assume that we have a producer which signal when it produces data. And in this method we create 'N' number of consumers.

```
public void StartMultiConsumers()
{
   //// main processor thread..

   while (true)
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          wh.WaitOne(); // causes the memory to grow crazy high
          wh.Reset();
      });
   }
}
```

I know that we can improve the code so that we dont create indefinite number of threads. But since TPL only create few ever threads. Why we have such a behavior.

`w.WaitOne()` causes memory to grow crazy high. But why?

Answer (score 3):

Each thread that gets created by the application, consumes OS resources.. You have a tight loop which simply spins off new Tasks as fast as possible, and solely rely on the throttling by the thread pool. But that won't last long, because as threads gets spun up and **blocked**, soon ThreadPool will inject new threads into the pool..

**Reason for memory spike** - Every thread created in .Net, is allocated a default stack of 1MB. There are also other system resources associated with the thread, but even with 1MB alone, if you spin off 1000 threads, you'd end up consuming 1GB memory for application, which is doing **nothing**, but **waiting** on the wait handle.

---

**EDIT:** To make it even more clear, consider the following -

- Thread 1 - Most notable system resource, 1MB of stack allocated. Held
  until thread is **alive (including blocking).**
- Thread 2 - Most notable system resource, 1MB of stack allocated. Held until thread is
  **alive (including blocking).**
- ...
- ...
- Thread 1000 - Most notable system resource, 1MB of stack allocated. Held until thread is **alive
  (including blocking).**

Total memory held by the 1000 **alive / blocked** threads - At a **minimum** (considering only stack allocation) - 1000MB. i.e. 1GB

Comment: but when I check into task manager I hardly get number of threads like 14. So that means that there are not so many threads or task manager does not show up the correct number of threads?

Comment: Also its not the number of thread that causes memory its the WaitOne() method that causes memory high. So if I comment this line there is no much change in size.

Comment: @DJ The wait one does not cause the large memory useage, it is the blocking call you made in the thread that did it. You could replace the WaitOne with `Thread.Sleep(10000)` and see the same effect.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, you are right. Means waitone is also a blocking call which cause the memory high but why the memory is growing when I make a blocking call?

Comment: @DJ Consider using the Framework's [Thread related performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat(v=vs.110).aspx) to count the number of threads instead of task manager. The runtime is not required to create an OS thread for every managed thread.

Comment: @mikez Thanks a lot. this is a new thing for me. I will go through it deeply now :-)

Comment: @DJ I've tried to make the answer even more clear with an Edit. Please check it out. Hope it clarifies.